# Controller Not loading in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 controllers in application/controllers

1. Welcome.php
2. pages.php

I am accessing welcome.php through this url

http://opunletter.com/index.php/welcome/

But while accessing http://opunletter.com/index.php/pages/

I am getting following error

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

I am Not able to figure the error. Plz help !

```
class Pages extends Controller {

    function search($search_terms = '')
    {
        // If the form has been submitted, rewrite the URL so that the search
        // terms can be passed as a parameter to the action. Note that there
        // are some issues with certain characters here.
        if ($this->input->post('q'))
        {
            redirect('/pages/search/' . $this->input->post('q'));
        }

        if ($search_terms)
        {
            // Load the model and perform the search
            $this->load->model('page_model');
            $results = $this->page_model->search($search_terms);
        }

        // Render the view, passing it the necessary data
        $this->load->view('search_results', array(
            'search_terms' => $search_terms,
            'results' => @$results
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your page controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `extends CI_Controller` and `construct()` like following:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($search_terms = '')
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And you should use controller name `Pages.php` (capital first letter) instead of `pages.php` in CI3.

Comment: CodeIgniter v2.x or v3.x?

Comment: You should use controller name `Pages.php` (capital first letter) instead of `pages.php` in CI3.

Comment: renamed the file to /application/controllers/Pages.php

Comment: You missed the method. You're trying access to `index.php/pages` and this mean `index.php/pages/index`.  Your controller have not `index` function, try with `search` method. `http://opunletter.com/index.php/pages/search`, It's working